# IE (9/8) bug is it just me?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, requirejs

So in my JavaScript app I am doing some dynamic script injection etc during runtime. Like appending script tags to the head of my document post page on load.

It seems fine if I go directly to the URL of the page through the navigation bar but when I do a right click refresh, IE seems to ignore any or all of my script tag injections.

Has anyone else seen this problem of have suggestions?

Don't see this in Chrome, FF, Safari.

I am using requireJS to do the injection if that makes a difference, but since it just does a `document.createElement("script")` etc. shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I gave up long time ago to make my scripts work on IE, you should do the same

Comment: I wish I could, but go tell a few hundred million internet users also. Ain't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem has actually that I am dependent on the load event ... IE / jQuery seem to be buggy in regards to maintaining the proper execution of onload for window. Using a timeout as a backup to dynamically inject the JS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try disabling the use of the cache on those pages. See this: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm

According to the article above, one method you could use to disable use of cache is to put

```
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
</HEAD>
```

at the END of the page